# Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened RMySQL

Tags: r, shiny, rmysql

I am very new to shiny and R but using shiny I am trying to connect to a database fetch the data from there. When I try to access my RShiny work on browser continuously I got an error like `Cannot allocate a new connection: 16 connections already opened`. How can I overcome this error or RShiny only expecting 16 users at a time? I have got another stack post here [RStudio Shiny Error mysqlNewConnection maximum of 16 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649673/rstudio-shiny-error-mysqlnewconnection-maxinum-of-16-connections) but the explanation was not clear on the above URL.

Comment: Do you *need* 16+ connections open at the same time, or are you looking for a way to close unused connections? If it is the former, [this blog post](http://fransvandunne.com/2015/07/allow-for-more-than-16-rmysql-connections-in-r/) seems to provide a solution.

Comment: Open one connection before `shinyServer` and use this one connection all the time.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Maybe you open a new DB connection with `obj <- dbConnect(...)` every time you send a query in your code. You can simply call `dbDisconnect(obj)` on the object you created to kill the respective connection everytime after your query executed.

Also you can use this function kill all open connections at once:

```
library(RMySQL)  

killDbConnections <- function () {

  all_cons <- dbListConnections(MySQL())

  print(all_cons)

  for(con in all_cons)
    +  dbDisconnect(con)

  print(paste(length(all_cons), " connections killed."))

}
```

I'd recommed to write a small function outside shiny that handles the whole opening and closing thing:

```
library(RMySQL)

sqlQuery <- function (query) {

  # creating DB connection object with RMysql package
  DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="youruser", password='yourpassword', dbname='yourdb', host='192.168.178.1')

  # close db connection after function call exits
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(DB))

  # send Query to btain result set
  rs <- dbSendQuery(DB, query)

  # get elements from result sets and convert to dataframe
  result <- fetch(rs, -1)

  # return the dataframe
  return(result)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @ThankGoat. This was really helpful and fixed the issue. But can you please explain from where i got the proper documentation for all these.

Comment: It's all in the documentation of the RMySQL package. Just type `?RMySQL` in the console and start reading ;)

Comment: I strongly advice use of `on.exit(dbDisconnect(DB))` just after `DB <- dbConnect`. Otherwise query syntax errors will leave connection open.

Comment: Nice one @Marek. Just edited the answer accordingly!

Comment: The `killDBconnections` function is nice. In case you want a quick fix. This solution [proposed in a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331440/2641825) will also disconnects all MySQL connections: `RMySQL::dbDisconnect(RMySQL::dbListConnections(RMySQL::MySQL())[[1]])`. To disconnect all  connections, run it interactively several times.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks, but whats the meaning of the `+` in this code `for(con in all_cons) + dbDisconnect(con)`?

Answer (score 22):

## Fast solution

If you get this issue, you should first run the following code interactively to disconnect all your connexions to the MySQL database:

```
lapply(dbListConnections(MySQL()), dbDisconnect)
```

(Note that you can replace MySQL() by another DBI Driver, if you use another database management system).

## Faster solution

Just restart R session : `command/ctrl + shift + F10` on RStudio

## How to avoid this issue

You need to tell shiny how to disconnect properly. That part depends on the use case. If you start a connexion each time you start shiny, you could add inside `server.ui`:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

Where con is your connexion.
If you start a connexion each time you run a query, you must disconnect immediately after the query has run.

You should also take a look at the `pool` package which is [suggested](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) by the shiny team to manage connexions.
There is also a very helpful section on [Shiny Articles](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/) on database.

Comment: The "Faster" solution is actually very slow if you have a large dataset loaded in memory...

Answer (score 0):

dbDisconnect() was not working in my case. So I had stopped MySQL server from terminal and again started using

sudo service mysql stop

sudo service mysql start

Then I ran the code with using dbDisconnect() now its working for me.